# Kafka create too many TIME WAIT TCP connection

Tags: tcp, apache-kafka, centos7

I use Kafka 0.11.0.3

I have a Kafka broker and a remote Zookeeper cluster. I start the Kafka server it successfully register its id in Zookeeper and I even can get the topic lists using the *kafka-topic.sh* command. The problem is I observe the following lines in the Kafka logs repeately:

```
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,138] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 192.168.0.201:9092-192.168.0.201:58292 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,198] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,226] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,306] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,327] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,382] WARN Attempting to send response via channel for which there is no open connection, connection id 192.168.0.201:9092-192.168.0.201:58296 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,408] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,446] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,559] INFO Creating /controller (is it secure? false) (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
[2019-01-08 10:51:09,602] INFO Result of znode creation is: OK (kafka.utils.ZKCheckedEphemeral)
```

The broker attempts to connect to the port 58292 on the same machine (that Kafka server is running) but it cannot establish the connection.
I also check the controller dir on the Zookeeper and it was empty.
More strange when I get the TCP established connections on the Kafka server node I observe so many **TIME_WAIT** connections:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55572     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56290     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55442     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55512     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56074     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56286     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55460     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55904     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55488     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56308     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55502     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56326     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55960     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55930     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56300     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56004     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55470     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55474     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55432     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55412     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56304     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55858     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55860     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56324     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55388     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56168     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55898     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55820     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55676     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56202     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55756     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56278     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55658     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55628     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56038     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56108     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55988     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55894     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55428     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55424     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56128     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56146     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55884     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56280     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55798     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56120     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55888     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55708     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55696     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56298     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55646     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56150     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55376     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55980     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55556     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56208     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55752     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55982     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55864     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55760     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56056     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56002     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55536     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55576     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55392     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55726     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55426     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55710     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56042     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56264     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55606     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55972     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56176     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55780     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56342     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55534     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55438     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56114     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56068     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55880     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56350     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55970     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55404     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55672     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55454     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55946     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56126     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55538     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56124     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55712     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56084     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55992     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56302     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55984     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55394     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55550     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56094     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55936     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55530     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55868     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:56294     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:55876     192.168.0.201:9092      TIME_WAIT   -                   
tcp        0     31 192.168.0.201:57552     192.168.0.204:2181      ESTABLISHED 1015/java
```

The only successfully established connection is for Zookeeper (at the last line). I also checked the port 9092 from a remote node and it was open:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-01-08 11:32 +0330
Nmap scan report for (192.168.0.201)
Host is up (0.0027s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9092/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

Some points:

- The broker was working fine for about 2 months and the error happened suddenly.
- The Zookeeper cluster is working fine because some other components like HDFS are using that and there is no error.
- The OS is CentOS7 and there is no firewall enabled.

Here is the Kafka server config:

```
broker.id=100
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.0.201:9092
num.partitions=24
delete.topic.enable=true
log.dirs=/data/esb
zookeeper.connect=co1:2181,co2:2181
log.retention.hours=168
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=40000
```

What can be the cause of the **TIME_WAIT** connections?

Comment: Not sure how many/how fast connections are made between the brokers/zookeeper, i think it is one and the others are waiting the final ACK to close the connection. Maybe network flood or lack of resources? You can scrap some more information by getting the log files under `/var/log/nmon` and feed them to NMOM visualizer (https://nmonvisualizer.github.io/nmonvisualizer/); also check kafka/zookeeper GC logs to find if there are slow downs waiting for resources

Comment: I think when for example `192.168.0.201:55388` establish a connection for `192.168.0.201:9092`, the port 9092 should return and establish a connection to 55388, too (I observe this in working Kafka brokers), but this doesn't happen and the connection from 55388 to 9092 will be TIME_WAIT.

Comment: You should be using at least 3 zookeeper, by the way. Definitely not two

Comment: @cricket_007 Using 3 node Zookeeper, or generally odd number of nodes for Zookeeper is recommended not mandetory! The reason is Zokeeper cluster is fault tolerant until (n/2) + 1 nodes of the cluster are up and working.

Comment: Well, you better be sure you're not able for lose any one of those. Unexpected power, or even network interuption. That's all I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar TIME_WAIT issue before, you may check your zookeeper log, default location is:

/bin/zookeeper.out

the cause of my issue is basically permission issue: I started zookeeper using normal user, but somehow the files under /zkdata are owned by root

the zookeeper log will tell you the reason